# Simultaneously updating two variables in an Excel VBA for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I built an excel spreadsheet containing a matrix of formulas.  They are all keyed off of a variable I've labeled 'var.'  What I'm trying to do is use a counter for 'var,' get the results from the last column of my matrix, and save those results to a new column.  'var' upticks by one, I get a fresh column of results, then I record them in a new column next to the first set of results.  etc etc.   I need 'var' to up-increment by one at the same time my column counter 'c' up-increments by 1.

I'm sure this is a stupid simple problem; I really appreciate any help.  I've posted a temporary solution below along with the problem code.

Where I'm stumped:

```
Public Sub Rows()
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, rev As Integer

'This is where I'm stuck; I need to update rev at the same time as c
For rev = 1 To 10  
    For c = 2 To 11
        Range("t1").Value = rev
        For r = 2 To 11
            Cells(r, c).Value = Range("A" & r)
        Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Temporary Solution:

```
Public Sub Rows()
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

'For now, I'm using c for both c and rev.  But rev won't always match c, 
so I need to figure out a way to update rev and c at the same time. 

For c = 2 To 11
    For r = 2 To 11
        Range("T1").Value = c - 1
        Cells(r, c).Value = Range("A" & r)

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

I tried different combinations to get 'var' and 'c' to update simultaneously, but I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58664609/edit) so include sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: `var` or `rev` ?- your question is a little confusing.  Please review what you wrote and make some edits to clear it up.

Comment: "But rev won't always match c" - you will need to explain the rules for how var/rev is modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Public Sub Rows()
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, rev As Integer

'This is where I'm stuck; I need to update rev at the same time as c  
    For c = 2 To 11
        rev = c - 1
        Range("t1").Value = rev
        For r = 2 To 11
            Cells(r, c).Value = Range("A" & r)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```